# Angular2 Menu bootstrap

Tags: angular, menu, css-transitions, bootstrap-4

I have build a menu with a toggle, it works fine.
When a user clicks a link I want the menu to collapse again.
I did this by making my own function this also works.

The issue I have now is that the toggle uses a nice transition when the menu collapse. I use show and hide so there is no transition I thought the transition w was reguladed by the css in bootstrap but I think this is not the case.

How can I add a nice transition to my menu when a link gets clicked.

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyMenu</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNav" >
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNav">
            <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/info']" (click)="closeMenu()"></span><br/>Info</a></li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/aboutus']" (click)="closeMenu()"><br/>aboutus</a></li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/contact']" (click)="closeMenu()"><br/>contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Bootstrap should manage the transition. If it doesn't, then you forgot something ! try just copy-pasting their nav and see if the transition works. If it does, then carefully look at what you're missing. And if you want your own function for the collapse, I suggest you take a look into [Angular transitions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html)

Comment: @trichetriche yes bootstrap does the transition when you click the toggle but I also want to use the transition when a menulink is click to have a smooth collapse

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it, please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment : if you want to collapse the menu, use Jquery to do so :

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function(){
    $('.btn-navbar').click(); //bootstrap 2.x
    $('.navbar-toggle').click() //bootstrap 3.x 
});
```

and to use Jquery into your compononent, underneath the imports, do

```
declare var $: any;
```

Comment: He is looking possible solution in Angular2. Can you please update it with angular2(typescript).

Comment: This is the Angular2 solution. JQuery is a Javascript library, meaning you can't use it in Typescript other than declaring a variable like that. You still can have a reference to `JQueryStatic`, but it's not what he asked.

Comment: @trichetriche Where do i add the jqeury in my component?

Comment: As I said, just underneath your imports, type in `declare var $: any;`. To explain briefly : `$` is a global variable, and declaring it allows you to use it (It's like saying `It's ok, I know this variable` to Typescript). if you want to test it, in your `ngOnInit()`, add `$('body').click(() => alert('hello'));` and click in your page, you will see that it works

Comment: Thx i will try it now!

Comment: Well I don't know, I don't have your code. You'll have to figure it out yourself !